# Data getting added suspiciously after Firebase call

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I am struggling with a uncertain issue and not able to figure out what can be the root cause.

I am calling Firebase for data using the below code:

```
public getAllObject(filters: Filter[]): Observable<T[]> {
  return this.afs
    .collection('somecollection')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      map((changes) => {
        return changes.map((a) => {
          console.log(a.payload.doc.data()) ==============> displays everything is alright
          const data: any = a.payload.doc.data() as T;
          const code = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { code, ...data } as T;
        });
      })
    );
}
```

and I am consuming the above service mentioned below:

```
this.service.getAllObject(this.service.getFilters()).subscribe(
  (entities) => {
    console.log(entities);==============> display's array and things are wrong.
  },
  (error) => {
    console.error(error);
  }
)
```

### Problem description

When I call the above API, I get an array of below objects. Problem is with the `stores` attribute. As we move forward in the array the stores attribute contains values from pre elements. This phenomenon is HAPPENING ON CLIENT SIDE only.

I was wondering if I am using attribute name 'stores' which is any kind of reserved keyword which is causing this to happen. Or i am using rxjs in wrong way.

### Current results

```
{ 
  code: 123,
  stores: { abc }
},
{ 
  code: 345,
  stores: { def, abc }
},
{ 
  code: 678,
  stores: { xyz, def, abc }
},
```

### Expected results

`getAllObject` `console.log` displays the following which is correct

```
{ 
  code: 123,
  stores: { abc }
},
{ 
  code: 345,
  stores: { def }
},
{ 
  code: 678,
  stores: { xyz }
},
```

### Current analysis

```
console.log(a.payload.doc.data());  ====> Showing correct
const data: any = a.payload.doc.data();
const code: string = a.payload.doc.id;
console.log({ code, ...data });
return { code, ...data } as T;      =====> Showing INCORRECT and adding stores from earlier element to current one.
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show your input data - what raw documents are you querying here?  We should be able to track the inputs to the final outputs.  There is nothing reserved about "stores".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display duplicate events after update firestore data, but the data itself in firestore isn't duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51108897/display-duplicate-events-after-update-firestore-data-but-the-data-itself-in-fir)